# How to load a ~/.vimrc then another local .vimrc

Tags: vim, vi

I would like to load a ~/.vimrc with general config (color, line number, etc) and then load another .vimrc i have in local file (with specific conf for python file for example).

Answer (score 6):

A local config would be loaded with a line like this in your `.vimrc`:

```
source ~/.vim/local.vim
```

You could put in that file settings that are particular to your machine, for example.

But settings specific to Python should go into either `.vim/syntax/python.vim`, or (more likely) `.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`. You do not need to source them, they will be sourced automatically whenever you open a Python file, as long as you have at least this in your `.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin on
```

(though I suggest you have `filetype plugin indent on` instead.)

Comment: This should be the top answer; the one-liner `:source ~/.vim/local.vim` from within vim was exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 5):

## Decluttering / structuring an overly long vimrc

Say, you have a lot of customizations and tweaks, and you'd like a bit more structure. For `:set`, `:map`, and `:autocmd`, you can just put them in a plugin script like `~/.vim/plugin/personal_customization.vim`. For plugin customizations (e.g. `let g:PluginName_Frobnize = 1`), you'd cause order-of-execution issues (unless you choose a `plugin` directory that comes early in `'runtimepath'` or use a special filename (`00plugin_customization.vim`) that is read first.

## filetype-specific settings

Vim has you covered here, but some people are not aware of it; [`:help usr_43.txt`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_43.txt.html#usr_43.txt) explains filetype-specific settings.

In short, if you only want to enable an option for certain filetypes, use `:setlocal option=value`, and put the corresponding `:setlocal` commands into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`, where `{filetype}` is the actual filetype (e.g. `java`). (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`.)

Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType {filetype} setlocal option=value` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations - this may have just brought you here.

## file-specific settings

To define special customizations just for a single file, my [ModelineCommands plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5767) can extend [modelines](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#modeline) beyond the built-in options that can be specified there by default.

For more extensive customizations, it will be better to source an accompanying Vimscript file (e.g. `foo.java.vim`) that lies next to the file (`foo.java`):

```
function! s:AutoSource()
    let l:testedScripts = [expand('<afile>') . '.vim']
    if expand('<afile>:e') !=# 'vim'    " Don't source the edited Vimscript file itself.
        call add(l:testedScripts, expand('<afile>:r') . '.vim')
    endif

    for l:filespec in l:testedScripts
        if filereadable(l:filespec)
            execute 'source' fnameescape(l:filespec)
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
augroup AutoSource
    autocmd! BufNewFile,BufRead * nested call <SID>AutoSource()
augroup END
```

Alternatively, the following local configuration approaches can also be applied to individual files (by switching on the current filename).

## local / project-specific configuration

This often comes up in the form of using different configurations for work vs. private stuff, different projects, etc. There are different approaches:

### Local config - central configuration

If it's okay to configure the specific commands / local exceptions centrally, you can put such autocmds into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/dir/* setlocal ts=4 sw=4
```

It is important to use `:setlocal` instead of `:set`, and likewise `:map <buffer> ...` and `:command! -buffer ...`.

On the other hand, if you want the specific configuration stored with the project (and don't want to embed this in all files via *modelines*), you have the following two options:

### Local config with built-in functionality

If you always start Vim from the project root directory, the built-in

```
:set exrc
```

enables the reading of a `.vimrc` file from the current directory. You can place the `:set ts=4 sw=4` commands in there.

### Local config through plugin

Otherwise, you need the help of a plugin; there are several on vim.org; I can recommend the [localrc plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393) (especially with [my own enhancements](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-localrc/tree/enhancements)), which even allows local filetype-specific configuration.

<sup>Note that reading configuration from the file system has security implications; you may want to `:set secure`.</sup>

Comment: Related Vimways article: [Attack of the 5,000-line vimrc](https://vimways.org/2018/from-vimrc-to-vim/)

Comment: Other answer was faster for what I wanted, prob also for other future users with my problem

Comment: @Nathan: The question is very imprecise - I'm trying to list all possible options in my answer, the other answer is for a very specific interpretation (that apparently matches your use case, so you liked that better).

Comment: Well hey this is just my vote, if others find your use case matches their situation, they are free to reverse my downvote-upvote combo and reward you instead :)

Comment: We appreciate your man-hours over years of contributions :)